# Trying to sort on 2 field for wrapper list. First on dueDate then on timeAllocated. Im having trouble with the CompareTo

Tags: apex, sort

```
global class TimeSortWrapper implements comparable {
    public TableData timeObject;

    public TimeSortWrapper(TableData t) {
        timeObject = t;
    }

    global Integer compareDate(Object compareTo) {
        TimeSortWrapper compareToTime = (TimeSortWrapper)compareTo;

        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (timeObject.dueDate > compareToTime.timeObject.dueDate){
            returnValue = 1;

        } else if (timeObject.dueDate < compareToTime.timeObject.dueDate) {
            returnValue = -1;

        } 
        return returnValue;
    }

    global Integer compareTimeAllocated(Object compareTo) {
        TimeSortWrapper compareToTime = (TimeSortWrapper)compareTo;

        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (timeObject.timeAllocated > compareToTime.timeObject.timeAllocated){
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (timeObject.timeAllocated < compareToTime.timeObject.timeAllocated) {
            returnValue = -1;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    /*
    private Integer sortMatchingDueDates(TimeSortWrapper obj) {
           if (this.timeObject.Project__r.Due_Date__c > obj.timeObject.Project__r.Due_Date__c) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (this.timeObject.Project__r.Due_Date__c == obj.timeObject.Project__r.Due_Date__c) {
                return 0;
            }

            return -1;
        }*/

    public Integer compareTo(Object obj) {
            TimeSortWrapper timeObj = (TimeSortWrapper)obj;

            if (timeObject.dueDate == obj.timeObject.dueDate) {
                return compareTimeAllocated(timeObj);
            }

            if (timeObject.timeAllocated == obj.timeObject.timeAllocated) {
                return 0;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my problem might be in the compareTo. Somehow it is supposed to call one method from another?

Comment: Advice for a good question, make your title concise, and expound in the body of the post.

Comment: How are you trying to sort? By one field then the other? Like `A[a], A[b],A[c], B[a]` etc?

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not answer your question leave a comment stating such and we can reopen it. I believe it answers your question though so......

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes like ORDER BY DueDate ASC, TimeAllowed DESC is what I was wanting in the query. Problem was I needed both a list of children and all parent records that don't have a child I had to go create a child for them and put them all in one list then order so query wouldn't work. And thanks for the heads up. Ill work on my titles :)

Comment: @Eric I felt like this was a new question. Ill remember that the next time I ask and then realize it would't work the way I asked before. My mistake

Comment: @AndrewMayes - So the answer in the indicated question does or does not answer your question?

Comment: @Eric I think I missed the one you added to it. I see the answer now. I only saw the one on the serialized sorting. Thanks